# MySQL insert only if NULL - any generalized flag present?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL insertion template:

```
INSERT INTO $0.$1 ($2$ColumnList)
VALUES ($2$ValueList) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

This is a MySQL command file (*.sqlcmd) which a program uses to randomly pass `ColumnList` and `ValueList`. So, I don't know in advance what are the values or the columns.

Now, I wish to make a conditional insertion to insert only if the columns are NULL or NOT NULL. Please note that I know I can write a MySQL statement like `where mycolumn IS NULL` or `NOT NULL`.

But are there any standard MySQL flags similar to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` type, which I can specify once and for all, and that helps me to get rid of mentioning individual column names one at a time with IS NULL or IS NOT NULL?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that sometimes `$2$ValueList` consists only of nulls and in that case you don't want to insert? Or is it that you want to ignore the insert statement everytime it fails because of a not null constraint.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Okay, to make it simpler we have a config file, where user has the option to specify what he wants. (1) He can opt for update the columns only if they are found to be NULL and ignore non-null values (2) Update only if the column has valid values.in which case all NULL columns will be ignored.

Comment: ??? An INSERT does not UPDATE.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry, i am correcting it rightaway in the main question.

Comment: No, there's nothing that processes all the columns automatically like this. You need to write explicit `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = IFNULL(VALUES(col1), col1), col2 = IFNULL(VALUES(col2), col2), ...`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, please add it in the answer so i can accept and close this thread. Seems like MySQL needs lot of improvements :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this automatically. You need to name each column explicitly:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = IFNULL(VALUES(col1), col1), col2 = IFNULL(VALUES(col2), col2), ...
```

Whatever script is creating the variable `$ColumnList` could presumably generate this `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause from the same original data.